# Ipad tableview doubts

Tags: ipad

I have a problem with my code

```
scroll=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    scroll.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    scroll.pagingEnabled=YES;
    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*5, 460);
    CGFloat x=0;
    for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
    {
        UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+10, 10, 300, 440) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        table.delegate=self;
        table.dataSource=self;
        [scroll addSubview:table];
        [table release];
        x+=320;
    }
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];
    scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
    [scroll release];
```

This is the code for the pagination through scrollview with tableview,but i need to put data in these 5 tableview cells that i create above.How to put data through these tableviews.(Data from xml parsing)

Thanks advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've correctly set `self` as the tableView's data source and delegate.

The table views will now ask for the data and you need to implement the [`UITableViewDataSource` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Each of those methods will get a reference to the table view that's asking for information, so you can use that to figure out which data to provide (for which of your 5 table views).

You may want to have a look at the [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451).